# Retrieve Firehose Redshift Destination username/password from Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Our Redshift cluster is subject to username/password rotation via Secrets Manger. We have a Firehose stream with the Redshift cluster as its destination. In our Redshift Destination Configuration is the username/password. Is there a way to automatically pull these values from Secrets Manager?

Answer (score 0):

The [`CreateDeliveryStream` - Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeliveryStream.html) documentation recommends:

> We strongly recommend that you use the user name and password you provide **exclusively with Kinesis Data Firehose**, and that the permissions for the account are restricted for Amazon Redshift INSERT permissions.

So, one option would be to **use separate credentials for Kinesis Data Firehose** and then *not* rotate those credentials.

However, if you do still wish to rotate the credentials, you will need to:

- [Customize the Lambda Rotation Function Provided by Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-customize-rds-lambda.html)
- Have the function call [`update_destination()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.update_destination) to **modify the stored password** (passed via `RedshiftDestinationUpdate`).